# change css on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to change my css on pageload but all I get is no styling. No error in console.

```
<script>

var condition = true;

setCSS();

  function setCSS() {
    if (condition == true) {
      $("#menuCSS").attr("href","css/css1.css");
    } else {
      $("#menuCSS").attr("href","css/css2.css");
    }
  }
</script>

  <link id="menuCSS" rel="stylesheet" href="">;
```

Comment: Where is that script located in your file?

Comment: So you're trying to select an element before you output it to the DOM? What do you think `$(function() {});`  (Or `$(document).ready(function() {});`) is for?

Comment: You also haven't referenced/loaded the jQuery library going by your posted code. Although if there are no errors in console I imagine you have just not in this question. Please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call setCSS() after the page is done loading. You can do that with

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      setCSS();
    });
```

Or as the previous answer said, add your javascript to the bottom of the page so the tag is already loaded before you call the function.

Comment: My answer above assumes jQuery because it was one of the tags in the question. You can do similar with jQuery as well.

Comment: best solution for me thanks ! Is it possible to specify a particular page also with the ready function ie if I would like a specific "external" page to be loaded?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for but you can replace $( document ) with another element to determine when it is ready, i.e. if you are waiting for a specific div to load you would put $('#divid').ready(....

Answer (score 0):

The script has to come after the actual link. The code runs from top to bottom. If you put the link under the script, it will not see it yet.